# read from multiple tables through express

Tags: mysql, node.js, express

I've been trying to solve this problem for over a week. 
I'm new to this node / express environment.

I managed to create a small web app with simple data through a local SQL database (MySQL). The problem is that when I try to call multiple database queries in a single function, I can not get the data.

I'have this function in a run.js file:

```
...
exports.list= function(req, res){
var id = req.params.id;

req.getConnection(function(err,connection){

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM run WHERE id = ?',[id],function(err,rows)
    {

        if(err){
            console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
        }          
    });

    var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE run = %?%',[x],function(err,results)
    {

        if(err){
           console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
        }   
        console.log("results: ",results[0]);       
        res.render('registration',{page_title:"registration",data:rows,data1:results});
    });  
}); 
};
...
```

Suppose I have 2 tables, one for users and one for run.
In the user table, I have a field where the names of the runs in which they participated are marked, I would like to return only the users who participated in a specific race.

In my run.ejs file I have the list of all the races and for each of them the button to see the users participating in it, referred to as follows:

```
...
<td>
  <a class="a-inside dett" href="../run/list/<%=data[i].id%>">List</a>
  <a class="a-inside edit" href="../run/edit/<%=data[i].id%>">Modify</a>
  <a class="a-inside delete" href="../run/delete/<%=data[i].id%>">Delete</a>
</td> 
...
```

Part of my list.ejs file is (both tables have a name field):

```
<div class="page-data">

        <form method="post" action="/run/list/<%=data[0].id%>">
            <table cellpadding="11" align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td class="label"><%=data[0].name%></td>
                    <td class="label"><%=data1[0].name%></td>
                </tr>
...
```

Reporting an error in this line:

```
<td class="label"><%=data1[0].name%></td>
```

I've also tried to change my function in other ways, but I always have an error.

```
...
var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM run WHERE id = ?',[id],function(err,rows)
{

    if(err){
        console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
    }          
});

var query = connection.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE run = %?%',[x],function(err,results)
{

    if(err){
       console.log("Error Selecting : %s ",err );
    }   
    console.log("results: ",results[0]);       
}); 
res.render('registration',{page_title:"registration",data:rows,data1:results});
...
```

This is from my app.js file:

```
...
app.get('/run/list/:id', run.list);
...
```

I need to know how to pass more query results to a .ejs file or how to call queries on the MySQL database directly from the .ejs file itself.
I hope I have made available as much information as possible to better explain my problem.

Comment: Is there a specific error?

Comment: This has no reactjs in it btw.